# replacing a particular number of an array by the number of that position of another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to write a function to replace a particular number of an array by the number of that position of another array. However, it does not allow me to do so. I am quite new in using MATLAB. Any help will be appreciated.

```
arr1 = [
    1     3     8     9
    2    47    10     4
    2     4     6    86
    6     8    11     4];

arr2 = [
    3 4  1  8
    8 2 99  1
    0 6 77 11
    9 3  2  1]
```

I want to write a function that will replace any particular number of arr1 with the number of `arr2` of that index. Suppose I want to replace `2` from `arr1`, then the output should be

```
out = [ 
    1     3     8     9
    8    47    10     4
    0     4     6    86
    6     8    11     4];

arr1(arr1==2) = arr2(arr1==2)
```

This allows me to do so. However, it does not allow me to write a generalizes function like

```
function new = arrayReplace(arr1,arr2,number)
    idx = arr1==number;
    new = (arr1(idx)=arr2(idx));
end
```

to replace any number of `arr1`.

Any help!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
function arr1 = arrayReplace(arr1,arr2,number)
    idx = arr1==number;
    arr1(idx) = arr2(idx);
end
```

or, perhaps less confusing:

```
function arr3 = arrayReplace(arr1, arr2, number)
    idx  = arr1==number;
    arr3 = arr1;
    arr3(idx) = arr2(idx);
end
```

Comment: Thanks! small mistake wasted my two hours just staring at the code.